pyautogui for multiple image upload
# click on Add Photo button
        captureinpsection.find(CaptureInspection.addPhotoButton).click()

        # List of file names
        file_names = ["Ceiling-1.jpg", "Ceiling-2.jpg", "Ceiling-3.jpg", "Ceiling-4", "Ceiling-5", "Ceiling-6",
                      "Ceiling-7", "Ceiling-8", "Ceiling-9", "Ceiling-10", "Ceiling-11", "Ceiling-12", "Ceiling-13",
                      "Ceiling-14", "Ceiling-15", "Ceiling-16", "Ceiling-17", "Ceiling-18", "Ceiling-19", "Ceiling-20",
                      "Ceiling-21", "Ceiling-22", "Ceiling-23", "Ceiling-24", "Ceiling-25"]

        for file_name in file_names:
            # choose photo
            my_image_path = rf"Downloads\Uploads\{file_name}"
            pyautogui.write(my_image_path)
            pyautogui.press('enter')
            time.sleep(4)

            # click on camera button
            captureinpsection.find(CaptureInspection.addMorePhotos).click()
            utils.wait_for(CaptureInspection.addPhotoButton)

I'm trying to upload multiple photos in one test, but after the first image has been uploaded, pyautogui opens the window in the Uploads folder again and then says "Path does not exist."
I tried adding os.chdir("..") above the loop so it would open one folder up but that didn't do the trick.
Very new to python, please help!

not sure if it helps you but I believe you can pass a newline separated list to send keys method... (use that on the  element.) Then submit the form.  You should probably use absolute paths for each file being sent.  (whether you use pyautogui or not)  Always good to run a quick test in your code to be sure each file exists before sending paths.
